# MongoDB: Aggregate on array elements with regex

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I use MongoDB v 4.2.17 where I have a collection of documents such as this:

```
[
  {
    a: 'a',
    b: 'b',
    c: ['apples', 'grapes']
  },
  {
    a: 'a',
    b: 'b',
    c: ['elephants', 'apes']
  }
]
```

I need to write a query that will return all documents, where any element of array `c` matches a regex provided.

I have a solution that matches the first element in the array:

`db.collection.aggregate([{$match: {'c.0': {$regex: 'apes'} }}])`

This query successfully matches documents where the **first element** in the array matches the regex.

I need to write an **aggregation** that would get the documents where **any element** in the array matches the regex.

I've tried this (didn't work)

`db.collection.aggregate([{$match: {'c.$': {$regex: 'apes'} }}])`

I need to use a `regex` and an aggregation, so a simple `find` won't work.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use the value `c`, not `c.0` nor `c.$`.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "c": {
        $regex: "apes"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Check [this example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Sjc3rOKYCJM)